# Schur complement condition for positive definiteness of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, schur-complement

To verify if a symmetric block matrix is positive definite, one can check the definiteness of its diagonal blocks and the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness) of the respective blocks.

Is this also true in the infinite dimensional setting?

Precisely, being $A$, $B$ and $C$ be linear bounded operators defined on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, it is true that if $C$ is invertible and $C^{-1}$ is also a bounded linear operator, then the operator block matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} A & B^{*} \\ B & C \end{bmatrix} $$

on $\mathcal{H} \oplus \mathcal{H}$ is positive if and only if $C$ is positive and $A - B^{*} C^{-1} B$ is positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $C$ is invertible, yes. The proof in the wikipedia article you quote does not use any finite-dimension-specific steps, so it works in the infinite dimension as well.

---

Now why $u_0 = - A^{-1} B^* v$ is the minimizer of $f(u) = (u,Au) + 2(v,B u)$ (I omit the last term, which is independent of $u$; also there is the adjoint $B^*$, not $B$, in the formula for $u_0$). This is quite easy: just "complete a square", i.e.
$$
f(u) = \big(u-u_0, A(u-u_0)\big) - (u_0,A u_0) +(u,Au_0) + (u_0,A u) + 2(v,Bu)\\
= \big(u-u_0, A(u-u_0)\big) - (u_0,A u_0) -2 (u, B^*v) + 2(v,Bu)  \\
= \big(u-u_0, A(u-u_0)\big) - (u_0,A u_0).
$$
In particular, $f(u_0) = - (u_0,A u_0)\le f(u)$ since $A$ is positive definite (note that in Boyd and Vanderberghe, the roles of $A$ and $C$ are opposite to your question).

I don't know what is there for Banach spaces, but you cannot define positive definiteness there, since the dual space is different.

Comment: Dear @zhoraster, thanks for the reply and sorry for my delay in accepting the answer. The proof of [Boyd's book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) for the finite dimensional case uses the fact that $u = -A^{-1}Bv$ is the minimizer of $$u^{T}Au + 2v^{T}B^{T}u + v^{T}Cv.$$
Could you give more details of how this is derived (in the infinite dimensional case) or indicate to me a reference that deals with optimization problems in Hilbert (or even Banach) spaces?

Comment: @shamisen, here you are.